# How to use $_GET when check if isset $POST in php

Tags: php, post, get

I have a url with change-password.php?id=1&key=37759

I am trying to get the values from the url and usind inside the if statement but I am getting a trouble.

```
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $key = $_GET['key'];
        echo $key; // this is empty
}
```

but if I echo them outside it works like this :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$key = $_GET['key'];
echo $key; // I get the value
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        
}
```

this one also does not work:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$key = $_GET['key'];
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        echo $key; // this is empty
}
```

this is the complete code for this page
change-password.php?id=1&key=37759 is set from the link that the user gets in their email when they request to reset their password. then it will take them to this page with the following code.

```
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $key = $_GET['key'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];
        
        $number = 4009;
        echo "test".$key.$number; // here I get test4009;
        exit();
        if ($password !== $confirm_password) {
            echo "Password do not match";
            exit();
        }
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM password_reset WHERE id='$id' AND key_check='$key'";
        
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
            echo "Check your email to verify that you have received the reset passoword link or try to resend the link again";
        } else if($row['expired'] == true) {
            echo "The link has expired";
        } else {
            $sql1 = "UPDATE password_rest SET expired=true WHERE id='$id'";
            $sql2 = "UPDATE user SET password='$password' WHERE id='$id'";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql1) && mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {
                echo "<span class='text-success'>password updated successfully</span>";
                exit();
            } else {
                echo "Failed to update password";
            }
        }
        
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Register </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
    .form-inline {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- /.col-lg-3 -->

        <div class="form w-60 m-auto mt-2">
            <h4 style="margin-top: 0.4em" class="text-center">Reset Password</h4>
            <form id="form-data" action="sell_parser.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password" name="password">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" placeholder="confirm password"
                        name="confirm_password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 btn-bg">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <p>To re-send the reset password link please? <a href="/afrolic/login.php">Click here</a></p>
            <div style="min-height: 12px;">
                <span id="results" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form-data").submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "change-password.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    //$("#preview").fadeOut();
                    $("#err").fadeOut();
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                    
                }
            });
        });
        $('#form-data').submit(function() {
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]
Please tell me what I am doing wrong here. Thank you for help!

Comment: Well, guess `$_POST['password']` is not set then :) Is that coming from a form?

Comment: if i echo something else when $_POST['password'] is set I get what I echo there. but when I try to concatenate the $GET value it doesn't work. I only see the string that I concatenated to the value

Comment: Well then in that scenario maybe the GET value isn't set. It's hard, what you're saying seems kind of contradictory, so we can only guess unless you provide specific input and output data. P.s. Don't forget that these variables don't persist between requests, if you want to read a variable every time then you have to send it in the request every time

Comment: I updated my post with a picture and code for the whole page.

Comment: Thanks. When you make the Ajax request to change-password.php you aren't passing any GET parameters in that request. In the opposite scenario, when the user clicks on the link in the email, it passes the GET parameters, but no POST parameters. So that's why you can't read the value from within the if statement. Like I said earlier, these parameters aren't persisted between requests. You need to send the same GET values again in your Ajax request, if you need them.

Comment: Btw most of this code is a security disaster. Making a robust authentication system is hard and there are many pitfalls. It's not a task for an inexperienced programmer. Most people use ready made components created by experts and then road tested and improved over time. These are either provided  as part of popular frameworks, or can be standalone. Rather than making all the same mistakes again, why not save yourself time and spend your efforts adding useful unique value to your application instead. Don't re-invent the wheel (especially not if you end up making a bad job of it)!

Comment: thanks for your help and comments. I will improve my code